# Haskell: how to properly see if a value is or is not in a list

Tags: haskell

Working on some practice haskell and I am making a search function in my program. I am not getting the desired output and I think I know why and that is it is only checking the head of the list and not the tail or (xs).  Here is what I tried..

```
searchtask [] searchkey = do
  putStrLn ""
searchtask (x : xs) searchkey = do
  if x == searchkey
    then putStrLn $  " Found task: " ++ x
      else if x /= searchkey then putStrLn $ "Could not find task." ++ search key

    else searchtask xs searchkey
```

Do I have to iterate through the list?

Comment: Your logic seems wrong. You first check `x == searchkey`, and when that's false you test `x /= searchkey`. Why? You already know the result of the second test, don't you? Also, when the search key is not the first element of the list, you can't really print "not found" without first inspecting the rest of the list. Try testing your code on a few examples like searching for `1` in `[2,1,3]`.

Comment: So I made a redundant else if with the x /= ?

Comment: Indeed, that's redundant. Below, chepner removed the redundancy and fixed the rest of the code. As an exercise, you could go even further than that, and separate the computation (return a boolean, without printing anything, similarly to `elem x list`) from the I/O (printing the result).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there's no need to check `x /= searchkey`. If `x == searchkey` is false, you *know* that `x /= searchkey` will be true. Second, since it can never be *false*, then your recursive call is never made. Finally, you don't want to print "Could not find task" until you've checked every value in the list.

```
searchtask [] searchkey = putStrLn $ "Could not find task " ++ searchkey
searchtask (x:xs) searchkey =
   if x == searchkey
   then putStrLn $ " Found task: " ++ x
   else searchtask xs searchkey
```

Comment: The code above is not compiling, missing a $ after the first putStrLn. FYI

Comment: And btw, the do keyword is a useless there.

Comment: I'm not sure if I just forgot to delete it, or if I was going to do something that would have required it (but then obviously didn't).